# Responsive with jquery changing width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am learning responsive desing I think that is easy for simple webs and usefull so I try to rebuid my web to be responsive. When my web starts I change the width with javascript in order to make an effect.

Well My problem is that when I change the width with javascript my responsive css doesnt work.

For example when I do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#content').width(800);
}
```

my css doesnt work:

```
/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

#content
{
    /*height: 450px;*/
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    position: relative;
    margin:20px auto;
    z-index: 0;
    left: -10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);


    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1);
    -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1);

    transition:width 2s;
    -moz-transition:width 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition:width 2s; /* Opera */

}
```

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your media query is looking at your browser's window width, not the width of the div. So you'll have to resize your browser window (which is not possible with JavaScript in modern browsers).

Comment: I dont understand it very well, if I change the window of my browser to 480 why dont set the size to 100% of the div? it doesnt work like a "window width listener"?

Answer (score 0):

`media screen` is condition of screen width, if `screen width > max-width` css not work.

```
max-width:480px; /* is for Smartphones (portrait and landscape) */
```

and

```
max-width:1224px; /* is for Desktops and laptops. */
```

here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u47su/) preview.

Comment: yes, but when I run my example it set the correct css, but the width dont update. For example in each css type (480 and 800) have diferent background color and it was applied but not the width :S